# Should "beachtennis" tag be "beach-tennis"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see that the tag [beachtennis](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beachtennis) got created today.  Beach tennis is spelled as two words.  Should the tag be [beach-tennis](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beach-tennis) instead?  I believe that is the convention for two word tags.

I tried to edit the [beach tennis question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5687/beach-tennis-rackets-with-most-control) and create a [beach-tennis](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beach-tennis) tag, but the system wouldn't let me create it.

Comment: The error message which I get is the following: *You are attempting to create the tag [beach-tennis]; however the tag [beachtennis] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.* I am not sure, how the error message looks for mods.

Comment: Some related threads on meta.MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184851/you-are-attempting-to-create-a-tag-however-the-tag-already-exists and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118027/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-hyphen-on-a-already-existing-tag-r2d2-r2-d2 (And probably a few more posts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I agree with you - the tag should be "beach-tennis" (two words).

I'll see what I can do. Thanks Ben!

Edit: I'm not able to edit the tag either, only suggest a synonym that can get merged later. Can only the tag creator (@edmastermind) edit it or is it set in stone for good once created?

Comment: This posts seems to describe what can be done by mods: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118027/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-hyphen-on-a-already-existing-tag-r2d2-r2-d2 (Not being a mod on any SE site, I cannot confirm whether it works.)

Comment: Tag has been renamed. Original request [here](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5687/beach-tennis-rackets-with-most-control#comment13315_5687).